# post() and get() are (re)directed to the same template

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
import webapp2
from views import MainPageCourt, CreateCourt, DeleteCourt, EditCourt, Listbox, \
                    MainPage, CreateLocation, DeleteLocation, EditLocation, Unexpected, \
            Schedule

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage), 
        ('/unexpected', Unexpected), 
        ('/listbox', Listbox), 
        ('/read/([\w]+)', MainPageCourt), 
        ('/create/([\w]+)', CreateCourt), 
        ('/createlocation/([\w]+)', CreateLocation), 
    ('/schedule/([\w]+)/([\w]+)', Schedule),
        ('/editlocation/([\w]+)', EditLocation),
        ('/deletelocation/([\w]+)', DeleteLocation),
        ('/edit/([\w]+)/([\d]+)', EditCourt),
        ('/delete/([\w]+)/([\d]+)', DeleteCourt)
        ],
        debug=True)





application: scheduler
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /create|schedule|createlocation|editlocation|deletelocation|edit|delete/.*
  script: main.app
  login: required

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: markupsafe                                                              
  version: latest 

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

For my primary class `class MainPageCourt(BaseHandler):` the def post() code is never read and I cannot figure out why. When I press the submit button on the template, nothing happens and there is no reaction in the gae log. I wonder if the problem is that I want both the post() and the get() to "finish" the same way by going to the same page, read.html? Is that a problem or am I looking in the wrong way and wrong place for my problem? If it is the problem, what is an easy workaround?

The first line below is for the post() and the second is for the get() of MainPageCourt.

```
return webapp2.redirect("/read/%s" % location_id)
self.render_template('read.html', {'courts': courts,'location': location, ... etc ...}
```

[This post relates to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268988/do-i-need-to-use-transactions-in-google-appengine)

**template added below**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p> You can start over at the beginning <a href="/">here.</a> </p>
<p class="schedule" style="width: 850px;"> 
<big>{{ location.moreinfo}} </big> <br /
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="{{ location_id }}"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="weekday" value="{{ weekday }}"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="nowweekday" value="{{ nowweekday }}"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="month" value="{{ month }}"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="month" value="{{ nowmonth }}"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="day" value="{{ day }}"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="year" value="{{ year }}"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="startTime" value="{{ startTime }}"></input>
       <input type="hidden" name="endTime" value="{{ endTime }}"></input>
{% for name in names %}
       <input type="hidden" name="court" value="{{ name }}"></input>
{% endfor %}
       <h1>{{ weekday }}, {{ month }} {{ day }}, {{ year }} at {{ location_id }} {{ location.venue }}</h1> <br />

       Make a reservation by (1) filling out table fields and then (2) clicking "submit". 
<div id="inputdata">
<input type="submit" value=submit />
</div>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" 
      cellspacing="0" class="sortable" id="unique-id" align="center">
      <thead> 
<tr> 
<td>Time</td>
{% for name in names %}
<td>{{ name }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr></thead>

    <tbody>
{% for time in times %}
<tr> 
    <td >
    {{ time[2] }}
    </td>
    {% for i in range(names|count) %}
    <td> 
    {{ time[3+i] }}
    </td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</tr> 
    </tbody>
</form>
</table>
  <br />

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I think you'd better show the template.

Comment: I assume you have a correctly defined form in your template.  As someone else commented maybe you need to show the template

Comment: @tim-hoffman I have added the template.

Comment: Also add your handler definition and you app.yaml configuration.

Comment: As I reported above, my get() uses this: `self.render_template('read.html', {'courts': courts,'location': location, ... etc ...}`. I have tried using another form, that may be required, but it does not work in my template because the `{{ for time in times }}` fails: `path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'read.html')`
`self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))`
Could that be a problem? I am using jinja2 and python2.7 and webapp2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no action specified in the form. In the form tag of your template you should add action=Url/Matching/BaseCourt.

Comment: I have tried adding all sorts of things like the following, but get no reaction. `"/read"` `"/read/{{ location_id }}"` . Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: You can add a URL/Class pair just to handle the post request for this form.

Comment: I don't understand, dallen. Do you mean adding an "href" hyperlink on the template? If so, why is that required in addition to the submit button?

Comment: No, you didn't understand correctly. Since you already added the action and it stills doesn't work, I suggested (as you asked for an alternative) to add a specific URL and a Class that handles just the action of the form. You will create a Class that deals with whatever is supposed to happen when the form is submitted and then redirect to wherever you want, you'll use the url that matches that class for the form action.

Comment: I am still a little confused. In the `<form action="" method="post" >` everything in the quotes for action is ignored in all my templates. Regardless, above I said I tried "/read" etc and there was no change. I have also tried totally new url's but they are ignored. Do you mean instead to add the urls to my app.yaml, or something?

Comment: I don't know why the action is ignored, "/read/{{ location_id }}" is the correct syntax. Yes, I meant adding it to the app.yaml otherwise the alternative I gave you would not work.

Comment: First, a new experiment tells me that if I remove entirely the `post()` no error occurs and I get the same result as if it were still present. Likely that is not a surprise, though. Second, I don't know how to add it to the app.yaml. Can you tell me? I thought maybe you meant also to circumvent the `{% extends base.html %}`, but I am not sure I know how to do that with the jinja2 included. Third, I don't know what it means to move this discussion to chat. Is that advisable?

Comment: I'll be easier than nerver ending comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16424/discussion-between-zerowords-and-dallen)

Answer (score 0):

In my template, immediately before the `<form action...` was an open tag: `<br`
With that fixed, the form is responding.